# git merging does not seem to work when directory names are changed or deleted

Tags: git

I have two remote branches develop and test and my local branch was set to test. I then merged the remote develop to my test branch and was successful. However, when I pushed my local branch to develop, my changes do not appear in the develop branch. The steps I followed are.

```
git fetch origin (Start at local test branch)
git merge origin/develop  (Resolved conflicts)
git push --force origin develop (says already up to date)
```

I had deleted some directories and renamed directories as well in the test branch. I do see all the changes in the remote test branch, but I am unable to get it on the develop. Any idea how to tackle this issue.

Comment: What branch are you on to start with? Have you done `git checkout develop` before the first step?

Comment: You should be careful with `push --force`. Only do that if you are sure what will happen.

Comment: `git merge origin develop` looks weird. When I do `git merge origin` I get `fatal: origin - not something we can merge`. `origin` is a remote, not a branch.

Comment: If possible, I would +1000 on the warning on `push --force`...

Comment: twalberg when the directory structures diverge substantially and you are sure that it is compiling locally and doing what you want, it seems to be the only way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
git checkout develop
git fetch origin
git merge origin/develop
git push origin develop
```

Notice the checkout and the slash in the `merge origin/develop`.

`git merge origin develop` does not make sense to me. `origin` is a remote, not a branch.

Comment: Thanks Klas just that I wanted to merge with another branch test and that did not happen even I tried to use the merge origin/develop. Now I edited the code above.